# How do you disable storing install directory in Windows Registry for install4j?

Tags: install4j

Install4J stores a registry entry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ej-technologies\allinstdirs*` in windows when running an installer.  Presumably it does something similar on Linux and MAC.

Is there a way to prevent this, and all other other permanent OS parameters, with a command line option? We run integration tests that actually run the installer and run then the application, but this then pollutes our registries, getting in the way of doing manual installations of the same application on our development machines.

Answer (score 0):

As of 6.1, there no way to prevent this. I have added this to our issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks - is there any publicly visible issue tracker, so we can see when this is fixed?

Comment: No, we don't have a public issue tracker.

Comment: Ingo Kegel, is this planned for Install4j 7, or anytime soon after?

Comment: install4j 7 has already been released. This feature has not been scheduled yet.